# The page has expired due to inactivity. Please refresh and try again

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

I am using laravel 5.5 when ever i send data in post request to my controller . It always show the following message
The page has expired due to inactivity.

Please refresh and try again.
my view code is :

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')


    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="span3 well">
          <legend>Create Your New Task!</legend>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-4">  
             <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/add-task" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
            <input class="form-control"   name="name" placeholder="Task Name" type="text"> 
            <input class="form-control"  name="assignedto" placeholder="Assigned To" type="text">
            <input class="form-control"  name="deadline" placeholder="DeadLine" type="text"> 
            <button class="btn btn-warning" type="submit">Add Task</button>
            {{csrf_field()}}
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>

    </html>

    @endsection()
```

and my controller is :

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
    use App\task;

    class AddTask extends Controller
    {
        public function insertTask(Request $req)
        {
            $name=new task();
            $name->name=$req['name'];
            $name->assigned_to=$req['assignedto'];
            $name->deadline=$req['deadline'];

            $name->save();

        }
    }
```

i doen't know what is the solution

Comment: Would it be a possible solution if you use the header for autoreload after some seconds? ` e.g.: <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" >`
You can also refresh the page with JS `location.reload();`

Out of the box i cant tell you why you get this error, but its possible that the csrf token reached the end of his "lifecycle". Every generated token is valid for a short time. There should be a setting in your laravel project where you can incrase the default lifetime of the csrf token.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46141705/the-page-has-expired-due-to-inactivity-laravel-5-5

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem using `localhost:8000`
Try below steps
1.Try on clean browser. It seems that the problem is with cookies from development with previous Laravel versions, on the same url.
2.Try to add `{{ csrf_field() }}` below opening form tag

```
<form action="/add-task" method="POST">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
```

3.and remove the `accept-charset="UTF-8"`

further reading
[Similiar Post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46170174/not-getting-the-error-token-mismatch-exception-in-verify-csrf-token-in-laravel-5)
and [Similiar Post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45994235/laravel-5-5-login-and-register-page-saysthe-page-has-expired-due-to-inactivity)
additional link about laravel 5.5 errors
[Larave 5.5: default error views and costomizing them](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-5-error-views)

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention on `php.ini` `mbstring.func_overload` parameter.

It has to be set to **0.** And `mbstring.internal_encoding` set to **UTF-8**. In my case that was a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Had to put 
`<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">` or use `@csrf` in Laravel 5.6
inside form.
`{{csrf_token()}}` otherwise would be printed in html page

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem but /storage/framework/sessions folder was missing.
Created the folder and that fixed it after a refresh.